# How to select elements with the same attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

I feel a little shame to post this question but eh there is no stupid questions, right ?

So here we go :
I have an element "A" containing only and strictly 2 elements "B".
I want to check if these 2 elements have the same value for the "test" attribute.

```
<A>
<B test="1" id="1"/>
<B test="1" id="2"/>
</A>
```

My xPath request : //A[contains(B[1]/@test/text(),B[2]/@test/text())]

But it is not working !

I can't wrapped my head around it, can someone help me here please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct XPath expression for that is as follow :

```
//A[B[1]/@test = B[2]/@test]
```

or if you want to use `contains()` instead of comparing the exact values :

```
//A[contains(B[1]/@test, B[2]/@test)]
```

Comment: Ok it is not what I was expecting but it works just fine ! I thank you sir !!